# Accidentally installed libphp-adodb on top of PHP 7 - how to uninstall safely?

Tags: php

On a server with PHP 7, I have accidentally installed the package libphp-adodb

```
$ sudo apt-get install libphp-adodb
```

This seems to have lots of dependencies to PHP 5, which completely broke my system and no webpages are working any more. The error message of the websites is

> The connection was reset

In the syslog I see all this PHP 5 stuff which I don't want

```
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-common: php5_invoke: Enable module pdo for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-common: php5_invoke: Enable module pdo for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-common: php5_invoke: Enable module opcache for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-common: php5_invoke: Enable module opcache for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-json: php5_invoke: Enable module json for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-json: php5_invoke: Enable module json for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-cli: php5_invoke opcache: already enabled for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-cli: php5_invoke json: already enabled for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:57 myservername php5-cli: php5_invoke pdo: already enabled for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:58 myservername libapache2-mod-php5: php5_invoke opcache: already enabled for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:58 myservername libapache2-mod-php5: php5_invoke json: already enabled for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:58 myservername libapache2-mod-php5: php5_invoke pdo: already enabled for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:02:58 myservername libapache2-mod-php5: apache2_invoke: Enable module php5
Mar  7 22:02:59 myservername apache2[4266]: Stopping web server: apache2.
Mar  7 22:03:00 myservername apache2[4289]: Starting web server: apache2.
Mar  7 22:03:01 myservername php5-mysql: php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:03:01 myservername php5-mysql: php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:03:01 myservername php5-mysql: php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:03:01 myservername php5-mysql: php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:03:02 myservername php5-mysql: php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:03:02 myservername php5-mysql: php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for apache2 SAPI
Mar  7 22:03:02 myservername php5-readline: php5_invoke: Enable module readline for cli SAPI
Mar  7 22:03:02 myservername php5-readline: php5_invoke: Enable module readline for apache2 SAPI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is the only package depending on PHP 5 stuff, I was able to remove the package as well as all dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove libphp-adodb
```

and the website worked again.